# Titanium Route Type missing and other issue

Tags: google-maps, titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

I'm building a tourism application that make use of native map view modules for Titanium (>3.2.0)

i'm apparently having 3 issues

- at any refresh with same coords in the same order the route seems to change,
- the route is being calculated DRIVING and there is no way to set it WALKING as of the documentation
- the route gets drawn once closed and once opened, even for this it does not seem to be an API or something to configure it

[image: Ti.Map.Route messed up]

Comment: Which Documentation are you following? and how are you creating the route, what have you tried?